# Implementing a form with 3rd party (Pardot) action while keeping jquery functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

My form operates with $.post(), triggered via a JS onClick, but now I need to alter the form itself so that its action is no longer = "#" but rather ="externalurl.com" where it gets its data recorded.

However, I'm lost as to how to implement this without losing my jquery functionality. If I just have it POST on submit, it might just page refresh with no confirmation of success or errors. Anyone have any ideas?

```
$("#go_places_FORM_submit_button").click(function() {

    $("#FORM_go_places").submit( function () {    
    $.post(
            'ajax/go_places_processing.php',
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){
                $("#go_places_messages_").html(data);
                $("#go_places_errors_").html('');
                $(".go_places_FORM_table2").slideUp(0);
                $("#go_places_messages_").slideDown(0);
                $("#go_places_messages_").html(data);
                $("#go_places_FORM_submit_button2").slideUp(0);
                $(".go_places_FORM_qr_code2").slideUp(0);                   
                $("#go_places_content_form_").css('background-image', 'url(../images/Imagine/go_places_bg_ty.png)');

            }
          )
```

HTML

```
<div class="go_places_FORM_">
<form action="http://www2.retailpro.com/l/19332/2013-10-14/75nwr" method="POST" id="FORM_go_places">
    //form fields
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you ever made this working?

Comment: @TomHert yes, can't remember if I had to abandon the ajax-ness of it or not though.